# C++ #include can't find file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I need to build this c++ project.

its failing on the line

```
#include <wkhtmltox/image.h>
#include <wkhtmltox/pdf.h>


fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wkhtmltox/image.h': No such file or directory
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wkhtmltox/pdf.h': No such file or directory
```

clearly its not finding the file. i have the file on disk but just need to point the project at it some how.

how do i set the project up so it can see this file?

Also If its not already clear, i'm a complete novice at c++

*edit:
i'm trying to build this: https://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf-bindings/tree/master/wkhtmltoxcom/*

*Visual Studio 2008*

Comment: Where is it? If you have it in your project's directory, replace `<` and `>` with double quotes `"`

Comment: Only problem with that is that it complains in image.h that it cant find #include <wkhtmltox/dllend.inc> and a whole other load of cascading errors pop up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goto "Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions" then select "VC++ directories" and select "Include files" in the combo box at top right corner. Specify the directory where the file is present. That should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you. that worked in solving that issue. Now i'm getting a load of 'error C2062: type 'int' unexpected' on lines like so ;CAPI int wkhtmltoimage_init(int use_graphics);' but i will ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to customize it per project, hit Alt F7 or go to Project -> Properties -> C++ -> General, and set the include directories.